# How to convert unit prefixes in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to know how to convert a sympy value with a physical unit into the same unit with another prefix. For example:

```
>>> import sympy.physics.units as u
>>> x = 0.001 * u.kilogram
0.001kg
```

should be converted to grams. The approach I have taken so far is very bloated and delivers a wrong result.

```
>>> x / u.kilogram * u.gram
1.0^-6kg
```

It should be `1g` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can accept printing `1` instead of `1g`, you could just use division:

```
>>> x / u.g
1.0
```

Otherwise, you'd better switch to `sympy.physics.unitsystems`.

```
>>> from sympy.physics.unitsystems import Quantity
>>> from sympy.physics.unitsystems.systems import mks
>>> Quantity(0.001, mks['kg'])
0.001kg
>>> _.convert_to(mks['g'])
1g
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This seems like a solution to me. Sadly in `mks` there are many units missing which would leave me defining the needed units before using them in `Quantities`. Seems inconvenient to me compared to e.g. [Pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> u.convert_to(x, u.gram)
1.0*gram
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to fully explain your answer. As it is, this answer is unhelpful.